# debug Aurelia ViewModel similar to ko.toJson

Tags: javascript, aurelia

in knockoutjs you can output the ViewModel in a nice json format for debugging

```
<pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($data, null, 2)"></pre>
```

if there is a way to accomplish the same in Aurelia

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could create a custom element.

**Here's an example: https://gist.run?id=9eea8902521f4523ee2c**

**app.html**

```html
<template>
  <require from="./debug"></require>

  <input value.bind="firstName">
  <input value.bind="lastName">

  <debug></debug>
</template>
```

**app.js**

```js
export class App {
  firstName = 'Donald';
  lastName = 'Draper';
}
```

**debug.html**

```html
<template>
  <pre><code>${json}</code></pre>
</template>
```

**debug.js**

```js
export class Debug {
  bindingContext = null;

  updateJson() {
    if (this.bindingContext === null) {
      this.json = 'null';
    } else if (this.bindingContext === undefined) {
      this.json = 'undefined'
    } else {
      // todo: use a stringify function that can handle circular references.
      this.json = JSON.stringify(this.bindingContext, null, 2);
    }
  }

  bind(bindingContext) {
    this.bindingContext = bindingContext;
    this.updateJson();
    this.interval = setInterval(::this.updateJson, 150);
  }

  unbind() {
    this.bindingContext = null;
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  }
}
```

**Result**

[image: result]

Comment: I think this should be marked as the answer - I've used this technique now myself and it works like a dream - thanks @Jeremy. Now that I know Aurelia doesn't deep check objects for changes (a hangover from my AngularJS days) I understand the need for the `setTimeout` although I changed the line to `this.interval = setInterval(() => this.updateJson(), 150);` since using the arrow function captures the `this` correctly (and I'm not sure what `::` is in javascript!!)

Comment: we really need to add this feature exactly like in knockout

Comment: I don't think we need the equivalent of `ko.toJson(...)`  because we use POJOs with Aurelia- we can use `JSON.stringify`.  What's probably lacking  is the equivalent of KO's `$data`... I don't think Aurelia has this feature.

Comment: The problem is that in aurelia you typically inject and attaches some aurelia objects (such as router or eventaggregator) to the viewmodel. Then you get a) a circular reference error, or b) your dump is 'polluted' with a lot of large aurelia objects. I'd like a way to dump only 'my' properties of viewModel. Any ideas?

Comment: @Larsi were you able to figure out how to dump only your view model properties?  I'm interested as well.

Comment: @Forest I ended up adding a "ignore-properties" attribute that simply removed the props before I did a stringify

Answer (score 4):

The closest I've got is to define a Value Converter. So in `json.js` I have

```
export class JsonValueConverter {
    toView(value) {
        return JSON.stringify(value, null, "\t");
    }
}
```

then in my view-model `index.js` I have my data:

```
export class IndexViewModel {
    data = {
        name: "nobody!"
    };
}
```

and finally the view `index.hml` binds and uses the converter:

```
<template>
    <require from="../resources/converters/json"></require>
    <pre textContent.bind="customElementModel | json"></pre>
</template>
```

However, I'm stumped at the moment by the lack of live binding between the model and the HTML so this may not fully answer your question?

Comment: My binding doesn't work because Aurelia doesn't deep check for changes and `<pre textContent.bind="..">` should read `<pre text-content.bind="..">`

Answer (score 3):

As an addendum to the answer of Jeremy Danyow, you can also use a [custom binding behavior](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/binding/latest/binding-binding-behaviors/7) on a particular attribute of your view model, instead of the *whole* view model. This has the advantage that you have control over the elements you want to see, therefore you can avoid the problem with circular dependencies (if you watch only those elements you *know* to be non-circular...)

First define a JsonValueConverter (same as the one in Phil's answer):

```
export class JsonValueConverter {
    toView(value) {
        return JSON.stringify(value, null, "  ");
    }
}
```

Then the binding behavior. Note that the binding notifies itself via a custom signal to cope with deep model updates.

```
import {inject} from "aurelia-dependency-injection";
import {ValueConverter} from "aurelia-binding";
import {BindingSignaler, SignalBindingBehavior} from "aurelia-templating-resources";

@inject(BindingSignaler, SignalBindingBehavior)
export class JsonBindingBehavior {

    constructor(signaler, signalBindingBehavior) {
      this.signaler = signaler;
      this.signalBindingBehavior = signalBindingBehavior;
    }

    bind(binding, scope) {
        // bind the signal behavior (ie. listen on signal 'update-json')
        this.signalBindingBehavior.bind(binding, scope, 'update-json');

        // rewrite the expression to use the JsonValueConverter.
        // pass through any args to the binding behavior to the JsonValueConverter
        let sourceExpression = binding.sourceExpression;

        // do create the sourceExpression only once
        if (sourceExpression.rewritten) {
            return;
        }
        sourceExpression.rewritten = true;

        let expression = sourceExpression.expression;
        sourceExpression.expression = new ValueConverter(
            expression,
            'json',
            sourceExpression.args,
            [expression, ...sourceExpression.args]);

        // send signal to ourselves each 150ms to update the binding
        this.interval = window.setInterval(() => this.signaler.signal('update-json'), 150);
    }

    unbind(binding, scope) {
        window.clearInterval(this.interval);
        this.signalBindingBehavior.unbind(binding, scope);
    }
}
```

You can put both classes in the same file, e.g. `json.js`. Then require it in your template:

```
<template>
  <require from="./json"></require>
  ...
  <pre>${myData & json}</pre>
</template>
```

... or make it available as a global resource.

**Here's an example: https://gist.run/?id=bde01135fa85f76202c72c11d3cb183a**

You could also extract the signalling to a second custom behaviour, just as Jeremy Danyow did in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33760616/1601438). With this in place, you would just do:

```
${myData | json & signal:'tick'}
```