# Update Aurelia observed property on change to containing array

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I have a simple class, `Event` with a computed property:

```js
import moment from 'moment';

export class Event {
    constructor(data) {
        Object.assign(this, data);
    }

    get playedFromNow() { 
        return moment(this.CreateDate).fromNow();
    }
}
```

`playedFromNow` just returns a string based on the `CreateDate` property, like `7 minutes ago`.

The viewmodel gets an array of events and the view renders the events. The array gets updated via websockets every time a new event occurs (every few minutes).

```html
<div repeat.for="event of events">
    <div class="media-body">
        <h4 class="media-heading">${event.title} <small>${event.playedFromNow}</small></h4>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the (relevant) viewmodel code:

```js
let  socket = io();
socket.on(`new-event`, (data) => { 
  this.events.unshift(new Event(data)); // add to the event array at the top
});

// subscribe
let subscription = bindingEngine.collectionObserver(this.events).subscribe();
// unsubscribe
subscription.dispose();
```

Currently the property is dirty checked, which means the property is checked and changes very frequently - this is a bit unnecessary and there are a lot of events shown on a screen so I'm concerned about performance over time. Is there a way that I can trigger the recalculation based on the array binding and update code in the VM?:

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The latest aurelia release has a new feature:  [binding behaviors](http://www.danyow.net/aurelia-binding-behaviors/) that will help with this use case.

First step would be to remove the `playedFromNow` property from the view-model.   We're going to put the logic in a value-converter to eliminate the dirty-checking and enable the logic to be reused in other views:

**from-now.js**

```js
import moment from 'moment';

export class FromNowValueConverter {
  toView(date) {
    return moment(date).fromNow();
  }
}
```

Now lets update our view to use the value converter as well as the built-in `signal` binding behavior.  With `signal` we'll be able to tell the binding when to refresh.

Change `${event.playedFromNow}` to:

```html
${event.CreateDate | fromNow & signal:'tick'}
```

In plain english this binding says, convert the date value using the `fromNow` converter and refresh the binding whenever `tick` is signaled.

Don't forget to import the value converter at the top of your view:

```html
<!-- this goes at the top of any view using the FromNowValueConverter -->
<require from="./from-now"></require>
```

Finally, let's fire the `tick` signal periodically...  every minute?

```js
import {BindingSignaler} from 'aurelia-templating-resources';

@inject(BindingSignaler)
export class App {  
  constructor(signaler) {
    // refresh all bindings with the signal name "tick" every minute:
    setInterval(() => signaler.signal('tick'), 60 * 1000);
  }
}
```

Comment: Following your answer and putting a `signaler.signal('new-event')` in my web-sockets event worked really well too. Thank you!