# Aurelia throttle on printed value with value converter

Tags: javascript, aurelia

Aurelia has *string interpolation*. If you bind a `string`, `number` or `boolean` to that variable, that is bound `one-way`.

However, if you bind an object and use a `ValueConverter`, like I want to, it gets bound `one-time`.

How could I use the value-converter to bind `one-way` instead of `one-time`?

I've tried using `${data | objectPrinter & oneWay}` but that does not work.

[Running code can be found on this gist](https://gist.run/?id=b66266719e47b4d04539e10326948cce&sha=68ccace29456995414fe854d0009c688061a78e6)

app.html

```
<template>
  <div class="row">

<!-- this isn't updated on change                 -->
    <pre>${data | objectPrinter}</pre>

  </div>

  <input value.two-way="data.branches">

<!-- this gets updated                            -->
  ${data.branches}

</template>
```

app.js

```
export class App {
  data = {
    branches: "test"
  }
}

export class objectPrinterValueConverter {
  toView(obj){
    return JSON.stringify(obj, null, 4);
  }
}
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Aurelia</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  </head>
  <body aurelia-app>
    <h1>Loading...</h1>

    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/jdanyow/aurelia-bundle/v1.0.3/jspm_packages/system.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/jdanyow/aurelia-bundle/v1.0.3/config.js"></script>
    <script>
      System.import('aurelia-bootstrapper');
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aurelia parses the text of your bind expressions into an abstract syntax tree (AST) and uses it to determine which properties to observe. It only observes the properties that are referenced in the expression.

In your example, the binding expression looks like this: `data | objectPrinter`. The expression accesses the `data` property on the view-model. This will make Aurelia observe the data property for changes.  *But it never changes*.  In your example, the view model's data property remains the same object instance.  The only thing that changes is the `branches` property which wasn't referenced in the objectPrinter expression, so it's updates don't cause that binding to re-evaluate.

Here's another way to create an object-printer:

https://gist.run/?id=9eea8902521f4523ee2c

Related question (ignore the accepted answer- it won't work in your case):

[debug Aurelia ViewModel similar to ko.toJson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32365884/output-aurelia-viewmodel-similar-to-ko-tojson/32369900)